# Delete btrfs snapshot with special characters in name

Tags: btrfs

In doing some testing with BTRFS I created some read-only snapshots using a timestamp for the name (i.e. including special characters).  Now I can't remove them.

```
$ sudo btrfs subvolume list /test
...
ID 387 gen 289 top level 5 path snapshots/2022-08-22 20:41:00
ID 388 gen 293 top level 5 path snapshots/2022-08-23 07:55:00
...
```

Trying to remove one:

```
$ btrfs subvolume snapshot delete /test/snapshots/'2022-08-23 07:55:00'
ERROR: Could not statfs: No such file or directory
```

Note I can get the stats for this file, and the snapshot is completely functional:

```
$ stat /test/snapshots/'2022-08-23 07:55:00'
  File: /test/snapshots/2022-08-23 07:55:00
  Size: 50          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 51h/81d Inode: 256         Links: 1
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/     que)   Gid: ( 1000/     que)
Access: 2022-08-23 00:00:04.349592125 -0500
Modify: 2022-08-23 00:00:02.257592094 -0500
Change: 2022-08-23 00:00:02.257592094 -0500
 Birth: 2022-08-16 12:14:14.154459488 -0500
```

I've tried various combinations to escape the file name, but nothing seems to work.  I see there is an `ID` listed, but it doesn't seem I can remove a snapshot by id.  Any ideas on how to remove snapshots with special characters in the snapshot name?

Comment: Your list command doesn't show the snapshot you're trying to remove. but I suspect that is just a poor choice of lines to show in that output?

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity My mistake.  It has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with characters (special or not). This is the command that failed:

> ```
> btrfs subvolume snapshot delete /test/snapshots/'2022-08-23 07:55:00'
> ```

`btrfs subvolume snapshot …` *creates* a snapshot. The subcommand is `snapshot`. `delete` is not a subcommand here, it's an operand to `snapshot`.

Your command tried to create a snapshot from `delete`. It's a shame `No such file or directory` is vague in this case. It would be better if this error was verbose and told you it meant "file or directory" named `delete`; this would give you a hint that `delete` was interpreted as a pathname, not a subcommand. Oh well.

The right syntax to remove what you wanted to remove is:

```
btrfs subvolume delete /test/snapshots/'2022-08-23 07:55:00'
```

where `delete` is placed where you had `snapshot`. `delete` is a subcommand now.

Comment: My mistake is clear now albeit rather embarrassing.  I must keep in mind that a snapshot is a subvolume.

Comment: @A.Que Not so embarrassing, regarding the fact the error message failed to be helpful.